# set a value in request body from lua script on kong

Tags: django, lua

I am using kong as API gateway and running a lua script to modify my api request. In my API request from server I expect, a authorization token & content type in header.

I wish to add a field, user_id in my API request body. How can I do that?

[my request from server has only authorization & content-type as you can see in the image (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLyZO.png)

[also my body has nothing from server as you can see in image (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqhqB.png)

but I want to add user_id in this Api request body(raw) via lua script.

P.s. I am then reading the body in my django application as `request_body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`

pls guide.

in my lua script I am trying

```
local form_data, err, mimetype = kong.request.get_body()
form_data["customer_id"] = customer_obj.user_id
form_data = cjson.encode(form_data)
kong.service.request.set_raw_body(form_data)
```

I get

```
{
    "message": "An unexpected error occurred" }
```

in response with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the issue. basically, I was trying to fetch the request body but since it was blank & nothing was coming from the server in the body, it generated the error.

So I only set my user_id in the request body & also modified the way of reading the body in my Django app since now json encoding won't be required.

```
kong.service.request.set_raw_body({user_id = customer_obj.user_id})
```

in Django, read raw data as request.data